# Disallow directory which contains a hash in Robots.txt

Tags: indexing, web-crawler, bots, robots.txt, google-search-console

Let's say you want to disallow a directory /#test/ (where the directory name begins with a hash)

I tried using the line: `Disallow: /#test/`

But, that didn't work, because, after googling a bit, I found out that the hash symbol (#) is reserved for comments within a robots.txt file, where everything after # on that line will be ignored.

After that I tried

`Disallow: /\#test/`

and

```
Disallow: /"#test"/
```

but those didn't work either.

Anyone know what syntax I should be using?

**Edit:** btw, I'm using google webmaster tools to test whether the robots rules work or not

Answer (score 0):

`#` is normally used as [fragment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), so you'll  probably have a problem to access it from browser.

So why not `Disallow: /%23test/`?

Comment: Just tested this in webmaster tools. The result is Googlebot allows urls in /#test/...

Comment: And how do you access this urls then?